# Why is MethodNotAllowedException thrown when an image is uploaded with CKEditor 5?

Tags: 9, wysiwyg

After updating Drupal to 9.5.3, I had this warning: `Deprecated modules found: CKEditor`.
So I upgraded from CKEditor to CKEditor 5 following this [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/3223395#s-ckeditor).
After some setup on text formats, I made some tests creating a basic page.
When I try to insert one image using CKEditor button, the image appears and immediately I get an error message saying `Couldn't upload file`:
[image]
After validating the message, the picture is not there anymore.
Looking at Recent log messages, I found this error: `Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MethodNotAllowedException: in Drupal\Core\Routing\MethodFilter->filter() (line 46 of /Users/efalzon/Sites/falzon/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/MethodFilter.php).`
[image]
I don't understand how it is relevant...
Any help?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! This seems to be more of a bug report than the kind of technical question that this site is set up to have answered.

Comment: Moving from the CKEditor module to the *CKEditor 5* module is not that simple. There are some settings to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have selected any language in "Administration pages language" in user settings try to set "no preference". This works for me in Drupal 10.

[image]

Comment: This fixed it for me on Drupal 9.5 as well.