# I can't upload images

Tags: media, updating, 10

I can't upload images with CkEditor 5 in my Drupal 10.1.6 website (which runs on PHP 8.2); all the other features work fine.

> [image: Can't upload image Ckeditor5]

In my recent upgrade of Drupal, I switched directly from Drupal 9.4 to Drupal 10.1.6. I followed [Upgrading to CKEditor 5](https://dev.acquia.com/tutorial/upgrading-ckeditor-5).

I've seen [ckeditor5 upload image MethodNotAllowedException](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3351241) where they talk about this problem. [Spokje's comment](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3351241#comment-15170120) says that issue is a duplicate of [AccessAwareRouter does not respect HTTP method](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2706241) which has been already fixed on September 18, 2023. So normally the issue should not re-appear, shouldn't it?

I also already seen [Why is MethodNotAllowedException thrown when an image is uploaded with CKEditor 5?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/314706/why-is-methodnotallowedexception-thrown-when-an-image-is-uploaded-with-ckeditor) but I can't find the user settings where I could change the language to default. In my website, we don't use this field on user. We just have *first name*, *last name*, *email*, *password*, and *state*.

I've enabled *Account administration pages* on /admin/config/regional/language/detection (*Detection and selection*).

In my admin profile, I can just update my mail or the password.

I can't find where the problem is. I have the [Editor Advanced Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/editor_advanced_link) module installed, but that is compatible with Drupal 10 and CkEditor 5.  (I've tested it.)

Can you help me please? I do not see errors in the Drupal log.

Comment: Are there browser console errors?

Comment: @cilefen, No errors in console when I try to upload the image, but errors when I am on the page : `[Deprecation] The keyword 'push-button' specified to an 'appearance' property is not standardized. It will be removed in the future.` and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at addEventListener 
    at edit?destination=/admin/news:1444:26124
    at edit?destination=/admin/news:1444:19767
    at xhr.onreadystatechange (edit?destination=/admin/news:1444:7693)`. Here is the [part of the JS code](https://prnt.sc/SqhPbkOurc3Z)

Comment: The "Can't upload image" error is set in drupalimageuploadadapter.js and it shown in the error handler to a JavaScript XMLHttpRequest. Are you certain there are no server-side errors logged? What is indicated on the network tab of the browser developer tools?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have a [https://prnt.sc/aUz4MItDYR_V](status code 200) on my image JPEG and on the link http://my-site/ckeditor5/upload-image/faq_editor?token=yVpALXfDePJA0sdXOjXRfn6sEiN3UIOJqpka_sz8YzA I have a [https://prnt.sc/R6Fr9a7xDqVU](302 found status code). I don't know if I search in right place

Comment: Ok my bad, I found the error, we had restricted access for the admin on our website with a function [https://prnt.sc/oeYshbs0B0zu]("isAllowedPath") on a AdminEventSuscriber. So we were redirected automatically to home admin (people list) page. Sorry for that and thnak you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, I had **restricted access for the admin** on the website with a function ["isAllowedPath"](https://prnt.sc/oeYshbs0B0zu) on a AdminEventSuscriber. So we were redirected automatically to home admin (people list) page.

```
   * Restrict the access to some paths for the admin.
   *
   * @param string $path
   *
   * @return bool
   */
  protected static function isAllowedPath(string $path): bool {
    return str_starts_with($path, '/admin') ||
      str_starts_with($path, '/editor') ||
      str_starts_with($path, '/entity_reference_autocomplete') ||
      str_starts_with($path, '/ckeditor5') || // Fix here --> Adding Ckeditor5 path
      $path === '/user/{user}/masquerade' ||
      $path === '/unmasquerade' ||
      $path === '/dqe/check' ||
      $path === '/views/ajax' ||
      $path === '/navigate/as/{user}' ||
      $path === '/user/logout' ||
      $path === '/system/files/{scheme}' ||
      preg_match('#^/sites/[a-z]{3}/files/styles/{image_style}/{scheme}#i', $path) === 1 ||
      preg_match('#^/editor/dialog/image/{editor}#i', $path) === 1 ||
      preg_match('#^/profiler#i', $path) === 1 ||
      preg_match('#^/cron#i', $path) === 1 ||
      preg_match('#^/views-bulk-operations#i', $path) === 1 ||
      preg_match('#^/batch#i', $path) === 1;
  }
```